# Expanding arguments before macro call

Tags: macros, expansion

I've been banging my head against this for days. I have a macro which takes a macro name and its arguments. It then re-arranges the arguments a bit and then calls the passed macro with the re-arranged arguments and so ends like this:

```
#1{\arga}{\argb}{\argc}
```

where `arga ... \argc` are the processed arguments. However. I need to have `\arga ... \argc` fully expanded *before* the macro stored in `#1` is called. I cannot for the life of me work this out after days of playing with `\expandafter`, `\noexpand`, `etextools` etc. I can't use `expl3` and I'd really prefer not to use `etextools` but `etoolbox` is available. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\def\x#1#2#3#4{%
  \def\arga{#2}%
  \def\argb{#3}%
  \def\argc{#4}%
  #1{\arga}{\argb}{\argc}}

\def\y#1#2#3{\detokenize{#1#2#3}}

\x\y{arg1}{arg2}{arg3}

\end{document}
```

This results in "\arga \argb \argc" but I want "arg1arg2arg3". `\expandafter` will do this in `\x` but not for three arguments in a row. `etextools` has some macros to do this but I really want to avoid it (it clashes with `etoolbox` in some ways and I must have `etoolbox`). I couldn't get the `etextools` macros to work even when I tried (`\ExpandNextTwo` etc.)

UPDATE: I realised that in my case, the args can contain robust macros like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}

\def\x#1#2#3#4{%
  \def\arga{#2}%
  \edef\argb{\ifstrequal{#3}{arg2}{arg2}{}}%
  \def\argc{#4}%
  {\protected@edef\z{\noexpand#1{\arga}{\argb}{\argc}}\z}}

\def\y#1#2#3{\detokenize{#1#2#3}}

\x\y{arg1}{arg2}{arg3}

\end{document}
```

In which case (using egreg's answer as an example), it isn't fully expanded. As Joseph and egreg mention below, this isn't doable, you just have to use non-robust macros in such cases, for example. I'll let the question stand as it because it is informative.

Comment: Is this your actual use-case? You want/need `\detokenize`?

Comment: @Werner I think this is a very simplified case: the `\def`s here are clearly just to illustrate the point, as you don't actually need them in the minimised case :-)

Comment: I don't need detokenize, it's just there for illustration, as Joseph says.

Comment: Robust macros can't be fully expanded, at least not in the way expected. Almost always they are robust because inside something unexpandable happens (like an assignment). That means you can't get out of them the 'text' or whatever, so it's a was of time worrying!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The 'classical' approach is to use `\expandafter`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\def\x#1#2#3#4{%
  \def\arga{#2}%
  \def\argb{#3}%
  \def\argc{#4}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#1%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\arga\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\argb\expandafter}\expandafter
          {\argc}}

\def\y#1#2#3{\detokenize{#1#2#3}}

\x\y{arg1}{arg2}{arg3}

\end{document}
```

where we need so many of them to expand `arg3` then `arg2` and finally `arg1`. (This is what is effectively wrapped up in `expl3`'s `\exp_args:Nooo`).

The rule of the number of `\expandafter`s we need is 2<sup>*n*</sup> – 1, where *n* is how many tokens we want to expand. So for one token somewhere ahead, we need just one `\expandafter` in each place to be 'skipped', to expand two tokens (second one then the first one) we need three `\expandafter`s, for three tokens (as in the current case) we need seven `\expandafter`s, and so one. This is easiest to see if you write/print out a short second and cross off the commands as TeX would read them: you'll find everything works out.

With e-TeX available, we can use an `\edef` and `\unexpanded`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\def\x#1#2#3#4{%
  \def\arga{#2}%
  \def\argb{#3}%
  \def\argc{#4}%
  \begingroup
    \edef\x{%
      \endgroup
      \noexpand#1
        {\unexpanded\expandafter{\arga}}%
        {\unexpanded\expandafter{\argb}}%
        {\unexpanded\expandafter{\argc}}%
    }%
  \x
}    

\def\y#1#2#3{\detokenize{#1#2#3}}

\x\y{arg1}{arg2}{arg3}

\end{document}
```

(You can do the same without e-TeX using a series of toks, but that gets a bit confusing so I'd not normally do it.)

---

The question says no `expl3`, but for contrast the approach using a minimium of the functions it provides would read

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\x#1#2#3#4{
  \def\arga{#2}
  \def\argb{#3}
  \def\argc{#4}
  \exp_args:Nooo#1\arga\argb\argc
}    
\ExplSyntaxOff
\def\y#1#2#3{\detokenize{#1#2#3}}

\x\y{arg1}{arg2}{arg3}

\end{document}
```

which is I hope a lot more readable. (I'd probably want to use `\exp_args:NVVV` as we are using 'value stored in a variable', but that function is not pre-defined so I've avoided it here.)

Comment: @cjorssen No, you don't need it: `\unexpanded` expands tokens looking for a `<filler>` (a sequence of space or `\relax` tokens), so it expands the token after it.

Comment: @cjorssen There was a question very early in the life of the site about this (where you can save unnecessary tokens). `\unexpanded` works in the same way as a toks, and the rule there is that TeX will expand until it finds the first brace. Very useful when you want to expand more than once: `\unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\foo\baz}`, _etc._

Answer (score 19):

If you really want the arguments to be *fully* expanded, then

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\def\x#1#2#3#4{%
  \begingroup\edef\z{\endgroup\noexpand#1{#2}{#3}{#4}}\z
}

\def\y#1#2#3{\detokenize{#1#2#3}}

\def\foo{This is foo}

\texttt{\x\y{arg1}{arg2}{arg3\foo}}

\end{document}
```

will result in printing

```
arg1arg2arg3This is foo
```

whereas the `\expandafter` based solutions would print

```
arg1arg2arg\foo
```

Comment: @PLK Robust macros such as `\ifstrequal` will never be expanded in a `\edef`; but also the `\expandafter` method would do essentially the same.

Comment: Why did you wrap `\edef\z{` in a group?

Comment: @dpatru It's a common idiom for not leaving behind a definition for `\z`: `\endgroup` will be executed only after `\z` has been expanded.

Answer (score 1):

With [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package, tricky argument expansion can be replaced by intuitive function composition, which is similar to other programmming languages such as `Lua`.

The evaluation of composite functions is from inside to outside. And `\Expand` is a predefined function.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{functional}
\begin{document}

\PrgNewFunction \x {Nmmm} {%
  #1{\Expand{#2}}{\Expand{#3}}{\Expand{#4}}%
}

\PrgNewFunction \xx {Nmmm} {%
  #1{\Expand{#2}}{\Expand{\StrIfEqTF{#3}{arg2}{\Result{arg2}}{}}}{\Expand{#4}}%
}

\PrgNewFunction \y {mmm} {\detokenize{#1,#2,#3}}

\x\y{arg1}{arg2}{arg3}

\xx\y{arg1}{arg2}{arg3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Only traditional (La)TeX:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\Exchange[2]{#2#1}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\x[4]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\protect=\@unexpandable@protect
  \edef\scratchmacro{{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
  % #1 can easily consist of more than a single token when using
  % \Exchange instead of doing "\expandafter-hopping"
  \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\scratchmacro}{\endgroup#1}%
}%
\makeatother

% \detokenize doubles hashes.
% Thus expanding \scratchmacro first halves the amount of 8 hashes of catcode 6 and you
% have 4 hashes of catcode 6.
% Then \detokenize doubles the amount of 4 hashes hashes of catcode 6 and you have 8 
% hashes of catcode 12.

\newcommand\y[3]{\detokenize{\y{#1}{#2}{#3}}}

\begin{document}

\def\arga{arg1}%
\def\argb{arg2}%
\def\argc{arg3}%

\texttt{\x\y{\arga}{\argb}{\argc ########}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Caveats:

- `\x` is not fully expandable as assignments are performed and grouping/scoping is used.
- A scratch-macro is defined from the arguments of `\x` and afterwards expanded. Expanding the scratch-macro leads to amounts of consecutive hashes provided as components of arguments of `\x` being halved.

---

If e-TeX-extensions are available, you can use `\unexpanded`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\x[4]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\protect=\@unexpandable@protect
  \edef\scratchmacro{\endgroup\unexpanded{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
  \scratchmacro
}%
\makeatother

% \detokenize doubles hashes.
% Thus expanding \scratchmacro first halves the amount of 8 hashes of catcode 6 and you
% have 4 hashes of catcode 6.
% Then \detokenize doubles the amount of 4 hashes hashes of catcode 6 and you have 8 
% hashes of catcode 12.

\newcommand\y[3]{\detokenize{\y{#1}{#2}{#3}}}

\begin{document}

\def\arga{arg1}%
\def\argb{arg2}%
\def\argc{arg3}%

\texttt{\x\y{\arga}{\argb}{\argc ########}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Caveats:

- `\x` is not fully expandable as assignments are performed and grouping/scoping is used.
- A scratch-macro is defined from the arguments of `\x` and afterwards expanded. Expanding the scratch-macro leads to amounts of consecutive hashes provided as components of arguments of `\x` being halved.

---

If you work with an engine where `\expanded` is available:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\Exchange[2]{#2#1}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\x[4]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\protect=\@unexpandable@protect
  \expanded{\endgroup\unexpanded{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
}%
\makeatother

% \detokenize doubles hashes.
% \detokenize doubles the amount of 8 hashes hashes of catcode 6 and you have 16 
% hashes of catcode 12.

\newcommand\y[3]{\detokenize{\y{#1}{#2}{#3}}}

\begin{document}

\def\arga{arg1}%
\def\argb{arg2}%
\def\argc{arg3}%

\texttt{\x\y{\arga}{\argb}{\argc ########}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Caveat:

- `\x` is not fully expandable as assignments are performed and grouping/scoping is used.

Benefit:

- No temporary macro is defined from the arguments of `\x` whose expanding would lead to halving amounts of consecutive hashes provided as components of arguments of `\x`.

---

The following variant is fully expandable as it does neither define a scratch-macro nor perform a `\let`-assignment for taking LaTeX's `\protect`-mechanism into account nor use  grouping/scoping:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\x[4]{%
  \expanded{\unexpanded{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
}%

% \detokenize doubles hashes.
% \detokenize doubles the amount of 8 hashes hashes of catcode 6 and you have 16 
% hashes of catcode 12.

\newcommand\y[3]{\detokenize{\y{#1}{#2}{#3}}}

\begin{document}

\def\arga{arg1}%
\def\argb{arg2}%
\def\argc{arg3}%

\texttt{\x\y{\arga}{\argb}{\argc ########}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Caveat: This variant does not take the oldschool `\protect`-mechanism of the LaTeX 2ε-kernel into account and fails with fragile commands.

Benefits:

- This variant of `\x` is fully expandable.
- No temporary macro is defined from the arguments of `\x` whose expanding would lead to halving amounts of consecutive hashes provided as components of arguments of `\x`.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a general-purpose macro that does exactly that:

```tex
% Macro `\expandargumentsof\macroname{arg1}{arg2}...\stopexpansion`
% *****************************************************************************
%
% Call a macro after expanding its arguments
%
\long\gdef\expandargumentsof#1#2\stopexpansion{%
    \edef\tmp{\noexpand#1#2}\tmp%
}
```

Syntax:

```
\expandargumentsof\macroname{arg1}{arg2}...\stopexpansion
```

For instance, without expanding the arguments, the following LaTeX manuscript will print “3—3—3”:

```tex
\newcommand{\mymacro}[2]{%
    \expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{#2}%
}

\newcounter{mycounter}

\stepcounter{mycounter}%
\mymacro{first}{\themycounter}

\stepcounter{mycounter}%
\mymacro{second}{\themycounter}

\stepcounter{mycounter}%
\mymacro{third}{\themycounter}

\first---\second---\third   % Prints "3—3—3"
```

If instead we use the general-purpose macro above we obtain “1—2—3”:

```tex
\newcommand{\mymacro}[2]{%
    \expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{#2}%
}

\newcounter{mycounter}

\stepcounter{mycounter}%
\expandargumentsof\mymacro{first}{\themycounter}\stopexpansion

\stepcounter{mycounter}%
\expandargumentsof\mymacro{second}{\themycounter}\stopexpansion

\stepcounter{mycounter}%
\expandargumentsof\mymacro{third}{\themycounter}\stopexpansion

\first---\second---\third   % Prints "1—2—3"
```