# imakeidx: Expand arguments before putting them into .ind file to ensure alphabetical ordering

Tags: macros, indexing, imakeidx, mfirstuc

In my document, i want to highlight specific words and add them to the index simualtaneously. The idea is to introduce key words with `\foo{word}`, making it appear typeset differently and appear in the index, so that one can quickly find the corresponding definition. Additionally, i want an optional argument for long key words, so that i can write `\foo[Word]{word with many adjectives}` to have **word with many adjectives** printed in the document and 'Word' appear in the index.

However, when not specifying the optional argument, i want to uppercase the first letter, as i want a capitalized index. This is useful when having a `\foo{adjective}` in the text (that should be typeset small), but that should appear capitalized in the index. For that i use the package `mfirstuc` providing `\makefirstuc{foo}` to output `Foo`.

I know that `\foo[Adjective]{adjective}` would do the job, but this is very tedious to write out each time.

I also know that

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{O{#2} m}{
\textbf{#2}
\index{\makefirstuc{#2}}
}
```

will not work, as it puts `\makefirstuc{<#2>}` in the `.ind` file, making it alphabetically ordered under `\` which is not what i want. This is also mentioned in the `imakeidx` documentation, but no fix is given there.

So i tried to use `\expandafter` giving me

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{O{#2} m}{
\textbf{#2}
\index\expandafter{\makefirstuc{#2}}
}
```

but then the argument is printed twice in the text and does not appear in the index. Also, [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104506/expanding-arguments-before-macro-call) has not solved my issues, i don't (really) understand it, and i did not get `expl3` to run properly.

So, how can i make `\index` expand its entry before writing to the `.ind` file, while not expanding it to plain text (like my second macro did)?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title = Index, columns =1]

\NewDocumentCommand{\fooa}{O{#2} m}{
    \textbf{#2}
    \index{\makefirstuc{#2}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\foob}{O{#2} m}{
    \textbf{#2}
    \index\expandafter{\makefirstuc{#2}}
}



\begin{document}
In this document i \fooa{highlight} some \foob{stuff} that i want to appear in the index in 
uppercase.
\index{Alphabetical order}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Note how the resulting order is not alphabetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\makefirstuc` is not expandable, but you can use `\text_titlecase:n`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title = Index, columns =1]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\fooa}{O{#2} m}{
    \textbf{#2}
    \index{\text_titlecase:n{#2}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\foob}{O{#2} m}{
    \textbf{#2}
    \index{\text_titlecase:n{#2}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
In this document i \fooa{highlight} some \foob{stuff} that i want to appear in the index in
uppercase.
\index{Alphabetical order}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This partially works, but ```\text_titlecase:n``` has the side effect that it decapitalises other words, turning ```\foo{adjective Noun}``` into ```Adjective Noun``` in the index. I really want to only change the first letter and let the rest untouched. In the ```expl3``` documentation I can't find ```\text_titlecase:n``` or similar commands, where can I find them?

Comment: The commands are documented in interface3.pdf

Comment: I can look later at the first word question,  I'm out now.

Comment: ```text_titlecase_first:n``` seems to do the job (at least for now it does what I want``` So thank you!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do I get this right?:  Neither `\fooa` nor `\foob`  use/deliver their first (optional) argument? `\foob` seems to have the same definition as `\fooa`?