# How to use \csname inside \xpatchcmd?

Tags: patching, csname

Consider the following example, what is the correct way to use `\csname` and `\endcsname` inside `\xpatchcmd`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{regexpatch}

\begin{document}

\def\foo{foo}
\def\bar{with a macro \foo}

\bar

% \xpatchcmd{\bar}{\foo}{bar}{}{\FAIL}
\xpatchcmd{\bar}{\csname\foo\endcsname}{bar}{}{\FAIL}

\bar

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think that the first two argument of `\xpatchcmd` are ever expanded. (BTW, at least it should be `\csname foo\endcsname`, but it does not work either). You need a bit of `\expandafter` magic, so I let it to other wizards. Are you sure this is not a "XY" problem? (But you can have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104506/expanding-arguments-before-macro-call, so you can see what I mean by `\expandafter` magic...)

Comment: @Rmano When I write the MWE I expected `\csname foo\endcsname` and `\csname\foo\endcsname` to be the same since the content of `\foo` is exactly `foo`. And true, this *is* a "XY" problem, I'm trying to patch command inside another command which receives certain names of macros as its argument, so I think using `\csname` here can be convenient.

Comment: @Rmano Actually I tried to use the `o` specifier in `expl3` without success. I believe an `expl3` approach can save us from those terribly many `\expandafter`s.

Comment: Yes I tried but got stuck in the problem of generating a variant `\exp_args:Nnonnn`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the next release of LaTeX there will be `\ExpandArgs` and you will be able to do

```
\ExpandArgs{nc}\xpatchcmd{\bar}{\foo}{bar}{}{\FAIL}
```

This is already possible in the development branch; if you run `pdflatex-dev` on the code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{regexpatch}

\begin{document}

\def\foo{foo}
\def\bar{with a macro \foo}

\ShowCommand\bar

\ExpandArgs{nc}\xpatchcmd{\bar}{\foo}{bar}{}{\FAIL}

\ShowCommand\bar

\end{document}
```

the console will show

```
> \bar=macro:
->with a macro \foo .
<argument> \bar

l.10 \ShowCommand\bar

?
> \bar=macro:
->with a macro bar.
<argument> \bar

l.14 \ShowCommand\bar

?
``
```

Comment: Nice! Is `\ExpandArgs` documented somewhere? I expected that in this case it should be `{nnc}`... ;-)

Comment: @Rmano You always want to jump over the next token, so the initial `N` is implied, see `\exp_args_generate:n`

Comment: Yes, but I thought that N←`\xpatchcmd`... aaahh, so `c` is applied to the expanded `{\foo}`, not to `{bar}`... (color me confused. I will need  a bit of time. And I found the docs, in https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex-dev/base/usrguide3.pdf)