# Using a foreach loop in LaTeX glossary to create a list of acronyms

Tags: foreach, pgffor, glossary

I would like to use a foreach loop to create a list of acronyms in a LaTeX document. I expect the code should look something like this but it does not work (it nearly works):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\foreach \x/\y in {
DOC/document,
ACR/acronym,
VV/very very,
}
{\newacronym{\x}{\x}{\y}}

\begin{document}

\section{Document Body}

A \gls{DOC} with lots of unexplained \glspl{ACR} is \gls{VV} annoying.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

For reference, here is an example of a working foreach loop and acronym glossary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{DOC}{DOC}{document}
\newacronym{ACR}{ACR}{acronym}
\newacronym{VV}{VV}{very very}

\begin{document}

\section{Document Body}

A \gls{DOC} with lots of unexplained \glspl{ACR} is \gls{VV} annoying.

\section{Foreach Loop}

\foreach \x/\y in {
DOC/document,
ACR/acronym,
VV/very very,
}
{\textbf{\x} \y\\}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [How to iterate over a comma separated list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159118) (There are many ways to loop.)

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. I understand your argument about writing out the acronyms but it seems cumbersome to write out the syntax every time  (particularly for standard glossary entries), especially if you have a lot of entries.

Comment: I understand but many LaTeX editors allow templates to be scripted so that it automatically places `\newacronym{}{}{}` and maybe even CCs the first to the second argument. That said, you could just do `\newcommand*\myNewAcronym[3][]{\newacronym[#1]{#2}{#2}{#3}` and then you only have to use `\myNewAcronym{DOC}{document}` without having to repeat `DOC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to [expand `\x` and `\y`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104506) before you hand them off to `\newacronym`.

In this case, it would be as simple as

```
\foreach \x/\y in {
  DOC/document,
  ACR/acronym,
  VV/very very%
}{%
  \edef\z{\noexpand\newacronym{\expandonce\x}{\expandonce\x}{\expandonce\y}}%
  \z
}
```

The name of `\z` doesn't matter (it even could be `\x` or `\y`) since it is forgotten after the loop.

Be careful with `pgffor` however, since its body is grouped, local assignments will not survive. The `glossaries` package evidently does them globally, though.

---

With LaTeX3 you can use `\exp_args:Nooo` which would expand each of the three arguments `o`nce before using them with `\newacronym`:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\MakeAcronym{ m m }{
  \exp_args:Nooo \newacronym#1#1#2
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\foreach \x/\y in {
  DOC/document,
  ACR/acronym,
  VV/very very%
}{%
  \MakeAcronym{\x}{\y}%
}
```

---

If you don't have to use the full power of `\foreach` (mainly calculating values and remembering others) you can use the [`.list` handler](https://tikz.dev/pgfkeys#handlers/.list) which would still allow the `...` syntax (not that it is really applicable here).

This does expand the values before it is handed off to `/GJ/new acros` which is why you simply can (and must) use `#1` and `#2` then.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\pgfkeys{
  GJ/new acros/.code args={#1/#2}{%
    \newacronym{#1}{#1}{#2}%
  },
  GJ/new acros/.list={
    DOC/document,
    ACR/acronym,
    VV/very very%
  }
}

% \ExplSyntaxOn
% \NewDocumentCommand\MakeAcronym{ m m }{
%   \exp_args:Nooo \newacronym#1#1#2
% }
% \ExplSyntaxOff

% \foreach \x/\y in {
%   DOC/document,
%   ACR/acronym,
%   VV/very very%
% }{%
%   \MakeAcronym{\x}{\y}%
% }

% \foreach \x/\y in {
%   DOC/document,
%   ACR/acronym,
%   VV/very very%
% }{%
%   \edef\z{\noexpand\newacronym{\expandonce\x}{\expandonce\x}{\expandonce\y}}%
%   \z
% }

\begin{document}
\section{Document Body}
A \gls{DOC} with lots of unexplained \glspl{ACR} is \gls{VV} annoying.
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]